# Internet Explorer 11 change event is not triggered after change the value of the input by javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am facing a problem with IE not Chrome. It does not trigger change event after I change the value by javascript. I think it work right as the specification of [event change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change). When user change the input by javascript then lose focus on the input that means user **does not**(javascript does) change the input. But Chrome is smart guy he knows user did saw the change on input so he trigger change :). Is there anyway to make IE behaves like Chrome?

```js
document.getElementById('inputName').addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
 this.value += '_';
});
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="inputName" value="name" onchange="document.getElementById('outputName').innerHTML = document.getElementById('inputName').value"/>
    <div id="outputName">name</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think any browsers trigger the change event when the input is changed via JS do they? I ran your demo in Chrome and the `onchange` is *not* triggered if the only change happened via JS (e.g., if you click into the field and just press the arrow or shift keys this indirectly changes the value via your keyup JS code). Even the MDN page you linked to says that the change event is only triggered when the user changes things.

Comment: If you change the value with Javascript, it's not a _keyup_  event. It's working as it's supposed to. If you want to trigger the event anyway, you need to use [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes I know. I want to make IE behave like that but it does not. Please try my code with IE -> input a character then click out you will understand what I want to do.

Comment: Maybe you should just use the `blur` event instead of `change`.

Comment: the matter is I have to use the change event, blur is annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed seems weird that the change event gets overriden by this js action... I guess specs are relatively unclear on this point, so I'm not sure if we can call it a bug.

Anyway, you can mimick this behavior yourself by listening to the input event, which will trigger every time the user did commit changes to the input's value.
From there, you just need to raise a flag that you will read in the `blur` event:

```js
inp.oninput = function(e) { // every time the user commits a change
  this._hasChanged = true;   // raise a flag
};
inp.onblur = function(e) {  // when we loose focus
  if (this._hasChanged &&    // only if there were some changes made by the user
      typeof this._onchange === 'function') {
    this._onchange();        // trigger our fake change event
  }
  this._hasChanged = false;  // set the flag back to false
};

inp._onchange = function(e) { // our fake onchange listener
  log.textContent = this.value;
};
inp.onkeyup = function(e) {
  this.value += '_';
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="name">
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

*Solution*:
https://jsfiddle.net/hrr3n0eh/

Comment: Thanks, but if you know Primefaces they put the onchange directly on the element. One more thing that if you input then you delete the character that you just input it is also consider as changed -> this is not right behavior of `change` event

Comment: @logger, you can rewrite all this without using the onevent properties but eventListeners, and instead of firing a fake onchange, you can trigger the real one. And for the second point, In your current code, it would fire the change event in all browsers since you do modify the value. But if you really need to handle this case, you could add an extra check to see if the value has really changed. Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrr3n0eh/) fix these issues?

Comment: Thank so much. I got your idea and I will try to apply. In fact it is more complicated than this example but it is good to keep up with solution.